# Display element outside of "overflow: hidden" in Swiper slider

Tags: html, css

**THE PROBLEM**

I have a swiper slider: http://codepen.io/kerowan/pen/xqYrwJ (recreate problem for example by giving `.product-info-wrapper` a fixed height of around 100px)

In the slides, there is an image and an infobox, which initially looks like this:

[image]

When I click on "Kurzinfo", the box needs to expand and finally look like this (the `.swiper-container` ends just after the *NEW* badge, so it has to *flow over the swiper-container*):

[image]

The problem is, that `.swiper-container` has an `overflow: hidden;` attribute, to hide the slides that continue to the right side.

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED?**

1) I have tried changing `overflow: hidden;` on the `.swiper-container` to `overflow-x: hidden;` in an attempt to just hide the slides which flow to the right, but show stuff that overflows downwards. This results in `.swiper-container` just adding a scrollbar, which lets you scroll down to see the content that should overflow.

2) I have tried changing `position: absolute;` on `.product-info-wrapper` (which wraps the box and the badge) to `position: fixed;`, because I read that the overflow attribute is ignored by `position: fixed;`. This doesn't seem to solve the problem, however.

I have not tried anything else yet, simply because I don't know any other solution approach.

**SNIPPET**

I pasted the snippet here, but it won't work, because I used SCSS and unfortunately lack the time to rewrite it to pure CSS. Can be copied to codepen, though, if the link above should die.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var productsInFocus = new Swiper ('.products-in-focus', {
    nextButton: '.product-focus-next',
    prevButton: '.product-focus-prev',
    slidesPerView: 4,
    loop: false,
    spaceBetween: 20
  });
});
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.product-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem * 5;
  margin-top: 1rem * 5;
  .swiper-slide {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 230px;
    .product-badge-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      .product-badge {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        &.red {
          &:before,
          &:after {
            border-color: #CF043C;
            background-color: transparent;
          }
          &:after {
            background-color: transparent;
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
          .product-badge-content {
            &:before {
              border-color: darken(#CF043C, 10%);
              border-left-color: transparent;
              border-right-color: transparent;
            }
          }
        }
        &.dark-gray {
          &:before,
          &:after {
            border-color: lighten(#000, 37.4%);
            background-color: transparent;
          }
          &:after {
            background-color: transparent;
            border-left-color: transparent;
          }
          .product-badge-content {
            &:before {
              border-color: lighten(#000, 13.5%);
              border-left-color: transparent;
              border-right-color: transparent;
            }
          }
        }
        &:before,
        &:after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          background-color: transparent;
          border-color: lighten(#000, 73%);
        }
        &:before {
          top: 20px;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
        }
        &:after {
          bottom: auto;
          left: -1px;
          top: -10px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 0 0 75px 75px;
          background-color: transparent;
          border-left-color: transparent;
          width: 100px;
        }
        .product-badge-content {
          height: 43px;
          padding-right: 5px;
          padding-left: 22px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: flex-end;
          align-items: center;
          text-align: right;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight: 700;
          position: relative;
          z-index: 10;
          color: #fff;
          &.text-small {
            font-size: .7rem;
            font-weight: 400 !important;
          }
          &:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 11px;
            bottom: 0;
            display: block;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: lighten(#000, 37.4%);
            border-left-color: transparent;
            border-right-color: transparent;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .product-info-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      .product-info {
        position: relative;
        padding: 1rem * .5;
        padding-right: 1rem * 2;
        overflow: hidden;
        &-link {
          display: block;
          a {
            color: lighten(#000, 37.4%);
            transition: color 400ms ease-in-out;
            &:hover {
              color: #CF043C;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
          }
        }
        &-price {
          color: #CF043C;
          &-del {
            color: lighten(#000, 37.4%);
            text-decoration: line-through;
            font-size: .9rem;
          }
        }
        &:before,
        &:after {
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          left: 0;
          z-index: -1;
          background-color: lighten(#000, 93.5%);
          border-color: lighten(#000, 93.5%);
        }
        &:before {
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 35px;
        }
        &:after {
          top: auto;
          right: -5px;
          bottom: 0;
          border-style: solid;
          border-width: 35px 35px 0 0;
          background-color: transparent;
          border-right-color: transparent;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .product-focus-prev,
  .product-focus-next {
    position: absolute;
    color: lighten(#000, 37.4%);
    background-image: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .product-focus-prev {
    left: -1rem * 10;
  }
  .product-focus-next {
    right: -1rem * 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b13050afbe.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content-wrapper narrow products-in-focus">
    <div class="product-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-container products-in-focus">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-7">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Amino Force</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-5 text-right">
                   
                    <div class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-badge-wrapper">
                <div class="product-badge dark-gray">
                  <div class="product-badge-content text-center">
                    %&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Basic Minerals</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-right">
                    <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-badge-wrapper">
                <div class="product-badge red">
                  <div class="product-badge-content">
                    new
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Amino Force</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-right">
                    <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Whey Isolat CFM</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-right">
                    <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-badge-wrapper">
                <div class="product-badge">
                  <div class="product-badge-content text-small">
                    nicht<br>auf lager
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Amino Force</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-right">
                    <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-badge-wrapper">
                <div class="product-badge red">
                  <div class="product-badge-content">
                    new
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Basic Minerals</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-right">
                    <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Amino Force</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-right">
                    <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/80x130">
            <div class="product-info-wrapper">
              <div class="product-info">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-8">
                    <strong class="text-uppercase">Whey Isolat CFM</strong>
                    <span class="product-info-link"><a href="#">Kurzinfo</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 text-right">
                    <span class="product-info-price">CHF 34.00</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-badge-wrapper">
                <div class="product-badge">
                  <div class="product-badge-content text-small">
                    nicht<br>auf lager
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-focus-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
      <div class="product-focus-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope my question was clear enough. If you need more details, please let me know!

Comment: Have you tried giving it additional padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution, I feel like it's a bit of a hack, however. For what it's worth, here it is:

```
.swiper-container {
  overflow: visible;
}
$slide: ".swiper-slide";
.swiper-slide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out, visibility 200ms ease-in-out;
  &-active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;

    @for $i from 1 through 3 {
      & + #{$slide} {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
      }
      $slide: "#{$slide} + .swiper-slide";
    }
  }
}
```

So, what I do here is setting `.swiper-container` from `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: visible` and then I tell every `.swiper-slide` to have `opacity: 0;` except for the `&-active` one. I then use the `&-active` slide as a starting point and iterate through a sass for-loop 3 times to add `opacity: 1;` for the next 3 `.swiper-slide`s. This sass code produces the following pure css code (`.swiper-container` not included here)

```
.swiper-slide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out, visibility 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.swiper-slide-active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.swiper-slide-active + .swiper-slide {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.swiper-slide-active + .swiper-slide + .swiper-slide {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.swiper-slide-active + .swiper-slide + .swiper-slide + .swiper-slide {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This whole stuff is just to remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `.swiper-container` while still showing only the slides I need to see and hiding the others.
Now I can play around with the height of the Infobox and the effect I was looking for works.

Comment: excellent solution, works perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: I've found that Opacity for Non-active Database images do not disappear immediately. Images from links e.g. https://shoesImage.png, will dissapear immediately.

Comment: I'm wondering how to fix this problem of database images not disappearing immediately, there's a 200ms delay.

Answer (score 11):

You can add:

```
.swiper-slide {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

where 30px is the value your badge should be beyond the border.

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/xqYXOq

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, that this pushes down the content that follows below the slider, which should not be the case

Comment: Awesome! Simple and working. Need to be the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
<style>
//as we want to see details which are being cut of by default css from swiper contner we change it top overflow visible.
.swiper-container {
    overflow: visible; 
}
//we changed over hidden to visible all slides of the swiper slider would we visible so we need to hide them so we add below css.
.swiper-slide{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
// now because of the above css all the slider are set to opacity 0 , which makes them not visible, now as we want to see out active and next slide we supply below css by using their name. and set there opacity to 1.
.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active,.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-next,.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-prev{
opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Use main class to change default css of swiper container. Here for you it is "product-wrapper".

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: I have added comments to explain a code.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem in my react project and solved it by wrapping up the whole swiper component with a div and giving it the following properties:

> `.sliderContainer {   position: relative;   z-index: 2; height: 25rem; }`

Another thing you gotta do is remove `position: relative;` from `.swiper` class like this:

> `.swiper { position: unset !important; }`

Doing this will allow you to bypass the `overflow: hidden;` of `.swiper` class and essentially will bind child elements to the wrapper div and you'll be able to expand your div as much as you'd like without it being cropped off by the slider.

Also when defining a height for the slider, you should add it to the wrapper `div` you created instead of adding it to `.swiper`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom padding, margin.

```
.swiper {
    padding: 13px !important;
    margin: -13px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You swipper should have

```
.swipper{
    width: 100%
}
```